# Prove these statements about trees are the same

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

Given a tree $T$ with $|V(T)| = n \geq 2$ prove these statements are the same:

1. There is an Eulerian path in $T$
2. There is a Hamiltonian path in $T$
3. The number of leaves in $T$ is $2$

I don't understand how can a tree have an Hamiltonian path, a tree looks like this:

[image]

How can you possibly travel on each vertex without crossing it twice? (Statement 2)

I would appreciate if you could help me solve it! Thank you!

Comment: Notice the third statement, which says that the number of leaves in $T$ has to be $2$. So your example with the red tree will not work, since it has $5$ leaves.

Comment: @Mankind Even if I remove the left sub-tree we get something that can't have a hamiltonian path.. no?

Comment: If you remove the left subtree, it looks to me like you will have a four-node tree with three leaves. Like the second four-node graph shown here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tree.html

Comment: @Mankind Wait so this should be 'pretty' easy no? I mean, a tree with only 2 leaves? if it has 2 leaves it must be this straight line or some sort of a continuous line... and then it must have a Hamiltonian path and if we have hamiltonian path we must have eulerian no? I am struggling to prove that though, because I am not sure if what I wrote is correct

Comment: This is an utterly simple problem. It is not about millions of possible trees. There are only a few trees satisfying one of these statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1)\implies(2)$ since an Eulerian path is a path that includes all edges, and hence includes all vertices because a tree is connected and has no isolated vertex.

$(2)\implies(3)$ since if there is a Hamiltonian path, the $n-2$ intermediate vertices of that path must have degree $\ge2$.  The sum of degrees of all vertices should be $2e=2(n-1)=2n-2$ and the sum of degrees of $n-2$ intermediate vertices is $\ge2(n-2)=2n-4$. To enforce connectedness, we require this sum to be exactly $2n-4$ i.e. each intermediate vertex to have degree exactly $2$ and each terminal vertex to have degree exactly $1$.

$(3)\implies(1)$ since the unique path between the two leaves is the required Eulerian path. How? By the above calculation, each internal node has degree exactly $2$. The tree is "linear" so to say -- an unbranched line.

Comment: Thanks for your amazing answer! By internal / intermediate  vertex you mean any vertex that is not the starting vertex / end vertex? Thank you!

Comment: An internal vertex of a tree is a vertex with degree $>1$ i.e. a non-leaf vertex. An intermediate vertex of a path is a vertex that is not the first or last (terminal) vertex of the path.

Comment: Thank you so much!